# What does the file.toByteArray() method do?

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-boot

I have to upload a file to the queue. But it seems that the toByteArray() method is not actually converting the file. Why?

```
        //upload the file to the queue
        File file = new File("J:/Documents/Head Fund  Share Class Attributes.xlsx");
        //convert to byte array
        byte[] array = null;
        try {
            array = Files.toByteArray(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //send the file data
        headFundUploader.send("helloworld.q", array);
```

Comment: Which `Files` class? The regular java `Files` doesn't have this.So you might be a bit more explicit in which classes/libraries you use. Also your code is flawed in that way if an exception occurs it just proceeds but `array` is still `null`.

Comment: import com.google.common.io.Files;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your code snippet is part of a class that compiles without errors, then you must have imported a `Files` class from somewhere other than the Java standard libraries.  (The standard Java SE libraries don't define a `Files::toByteArray` method.)

Without seeing your entire class, we can only guess which 3rd-party library that is ... so this is an educated guess.

There is a `Files::toByteArray(File)` method in the Guava (Google commons) library.  The [javadoc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html) for the method says this:

> `public static byte[] toByteArray(File file) throws IOException`
>
> Reads all bytes from a file into a byte array.
>
> Path equivalent: `Files.readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)`.

---

> But it seems that the toByteArray() method is not actually converting the file. Why?

It depends what you mean by "converting".  The actual documented purpose of the method is to simply read the bytes of the file without any character set decoding or other conversion.  But I suppose you could call that "converting" the file content to an array of bytes.

---

If you a more detailed answer, you will need to:

- confirm which `Files` class you are importing (*you have done that!*),
- tell us what you mean by "converting", and
- tell us what happens when you run that code in you application, and why you think it isn't "converting" the file.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think what you wanted to use [Files.readAllBytes(Path).](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path))

to do this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;

File file = new File("J:/Documents/Head Fund  Share Class Attributes.xlsx");
byte[] array = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
```

Comment: Instead of `File file = ... file.toPath()` you can use `Paths.get("")`

Comment: @rkosegi Is it better to use Paths.get("")?

Comment: Why create intermediate `File` object just to convert it to `Path`?

Comment: @rkosegi You are right of course. I omitted the code that checks if the file exists... If you are sure that it does exist it's MUCH MUCH better to use Paths.